# how to repair vim error 'E148: Regular expression missing from global '?

Tags: linux, vim

I installed ubuntu using virtual machine in my mac recently. In the ubuntu, I installed vim and open a source code file, after that, I type `:1s` to go first line.

But, this command does not work! vim repeatedly show error message like this.

```
E148: Regular expression missing from global
```

When I type the same command in mac, I have no problem with that even though I didn't do any setting option. I'm confused with this.... Help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `:1` to jump to the first line (or `gg` or `1G` in normal mode).

`:1s` is the command `:s[ubstitute]` with range `1`. Without `/pattern/string/`, `s` will repeat the last substitution.

Answer (score -1):

You might need an empty line at the end of your .vimrc file

Comment: Sorry, what? This doesnt make sense, or address the problem

Comment: So don't do it. It fixed the problem for me. It was the only change I made and the error went away so, I thought that It might help someone else. It is harmless and easy but you don't have to try it.